# Angular2 Subcribe variable undefined

Tags: angular

I'm facing the following problem:

I try to get data from JSON and bring it to my front-end.

To connect to the JSON I have the following code in `service.ts`

```
getSentiment(text: string){
    var sentimentdata = {
        'text': text
    };

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/analyse', sentimentdata, { headers: headers })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response.json());
            response.json();
        })
}
```

Where I get the following in my console:

```
Object { analysis: "0.49527" }
```

I call the service in my `component.ts` in the following way:

```
this.service.getSentiment(this.model.text).subscribe(
    res => {
        this.score = res;
            console.log(this.score);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
);
```

Which gives me the following output: `undefined`

I've been looking like crazy how to get rid of the undefined. How is it available on the service side but not in my component?

Comment: is `score` variable declared in the object? Try to `console.log(res)` instead of `console.log(this.score)` to see if anything changes.

Comment: score: any; is defined at the top of the component. Did both console logs and get two times undefined.

Comment: You map method should have a return statement i believe `return response.json()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your arrow function:

```
.map (res => res.json()) <- automatic return
```

However:

```
.map((response: Response) => {console.log(response.json());response.json();}) <- curly brackets in your arrow function, NO automatic return.
```

So

```
.map((response: Response) => {console.log(response.json());return response.json();})
```

will fix it.